Limit I_error in ROS2 PID Controller to Prevent Windup
I am applying ROS2 PID controller on my motors, however - due to my setup - the integral error keeps growing. I set I_clamp max and min to the controller to prevent high values but since the I_error is high the controller response afterwards is slow. Can I set a limit to the I_error so it doesn't keep winding up?
My config parameters look like this:
joint0: {p: 0.02204, i: 48.04, d: 0.0, i_clamp_max: 0.5, i_clamp_min: -0.5}


Windup is not definitely solved by decreasing $K_I$, it only slows Wind-Ups. Any good controller will have an Anti-Windup-Feature implemented though, including the ROS2-Control package where you simply need to set the parameter:
gains.<dof_names>.antiwindup (bool)
Antiwindup functionality.

Default: false

to true.

Thank you for your answer but that's irrelevant. I wanted to limit I_erro not I_gain (Ki). Also, the antinwindup functionality in PID here only allows me to set I_clamp max and min which I already use.

I would guess you mean to limit $I_{error} = K_I \int e$ where $e$ is the control error? Do you not effectively limit $I_{error}$ by using Anti-Windup and Clamping? If your controller response is too slow, should you not look into setting $K$ and $K_P$ higher? $K_I$ will always respond slowly due to its integrative nature - with or without clamping.

Control error (e) in your equation is what I'm looking to limit. Not the control signal. As I can indeed limit the control signal (which you refer to I error). I hope this clarifies it.

Could you motivate on why you would like to limit control error $e$? Your question makes it seem like you had problems with $K_I \int e$ but now, it seems the problem is different.

So I'm doing torque (effort) control, if I command the motor while it's not loaded for sometime (it might happen at my setup) it can't reach the required torque due to saturation, thus the i_error will keep increasing. Now if I lower the commanded torque the motor will respond slowly due to the accumulated I_error, that's why I want to limit the I_error so it doesn't exceed some value even if the motor is not reaching it's commanded torque because I know it's saturated at the moment.
